# how can I cross-compile to darwin 386 from linux?

Tags: go, compilation, cross-compiling, darwin, i386

I am trying to compile from linux using:

```
GOOS=darwin GOARCH=386 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build .
```

but it throws the error:

```
cmd/go: unsupported GOOS/GOARCH pair darwin/386
```

I looked everywhere but it seems that darwin/386 should be supported
(compilation for windows/386 and linux/386 work fine)
(compilation for darwin/amd64 works fine)

(I even tried on windows but the error is the same)

What am I missing?

Comment: Beside what the error tells you: Running go  build with filename arguments is **wrong**.

Comment: ok @Volker and what is the correct/accepted way?

Comment: `go build`. Mabye `go build .` or `go build <packagename>`. No subcommand of the go tool works on _files_ (at least not reliable and how you think it does). Btw: Running `go help build` explains how to use go build and there is nothing wrong with always consulting the official documentation and builtin help first.

Comment: even if I only have one .go file?

Comment: As the error says, that OS/arch pair is not supported. It's not relevant what other OS/arch pairs *are* supported; that one isn't. Support was removed because macOS no longer supports 32-bit binaries.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Go 1.15 release notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.15):

> As announced in the Go 1.14 release notes, Go 1.15 drops support for 32-bit binaries on macOS, iOS, iPadOS, watchOS, and tvOS (the darwin/386 and darwin/arm ports). Go continues to support the 64-bit darwin/amd64 and darwin/arm64 ports.

You can use Go 1.14 to compile to darwin/386 if needed. The latest OSX versions do not run any 32bit programs any more (from Catalina). That is the reason they dropped the support: [Go 1.14 release notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.14#darwin) announced that.